# __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Tags: django

**Error**

```
response = callback(request,*callback_args,**callback_kwargs)
Exception Type: TypeError at /accounts/profile/
Exception Value: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Here is my code

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset, password_reset_done, password_change, password_change_done
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('', (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
    (r'^accounts/profile/$', TemplateView, {'template': 'registration/profile.html'}),
    (r'^accounts/password_reset/$', password_reset, {'template_name': 'registration/password_reset.html'}),
    (r'^accounts/password_reset_done/$', password_reset_done, {'template_name': 'registration/password_reset_done.html'}),
    (r'^accounts/password_change/$', password_change, {'template_name': 'registration/password_change.html'}),
    (r'^accounts/password_change_done/$', password_change_done, {'template_name': 'registration/password_change_done.html'}),
)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from models import RegistrationProfile
from forms import RegistrationForm
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def activate(request, activation_key):
    activation_key = activation_key.lower() # Normalize before trying anything with it.
    account = RegistrationProfile.objects.activate_user(activation_key)
    return render_to_response('registration/activate.html',{
        'account': account, 
        'expiration_days': settings.ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS 
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

c = {} c.update(csrf(request))

def register(request, success_url='/accounts/register/complete/'):
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid(): 
            new_user=RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'], 
                password=form.cleaned_data['password1'], 
                email=form.cleaned_data['email']
                )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)

    return render_to_response('registration/registration_form.html', { 
        'form': form 
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Can anyone help me to fix this error. Thanks in advance

Comment: How can we help you if you didn't post your codes???

Comment: where is your views codes for profile?

Comment: Please next time arrange your codes.

Comment: I don't see your registration/profile.html

Answer (score 19):

Your current error is caused by passing `TemplateView` into your url conf. It should be `TemplateView.as_view()`.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    #...
    (r'^accounts/profile/$', TemplateView.as_view(template= 'registration/profile.html')),
    #...
)
```

Comment: Thanks.. Forgot to add it and that error message did not help.

Comment: Post got downvoted hard, but this was very useful. Django could do with a helpful error message when you pass the class but not the `as_view()` version to URLs.

Comment: Not sure which version this is appropriate to, but in django 1.6, the keyword should be `template_name` rather than `template`.